# Escaping Prisoner Probability Question

Tags: probability, statistics

**Question:** A prisoner is trapped in a cell containing three doors. The first door leads to a tunnel which
returns him to his cell after two days travel. The second door leads to a tunnel that returns
him to his cell after three days travel. The third door leads immediately to freedom.

(a) Assuming the prisoner will always select doors 1, 2 and 3 with probabilities 0.5, 0.3 and
0.2 respectively, what is the expected number of days until he reaches freedom?

(b) Calculate the variance of the number of days until the prisoner reaches freedom.

**My Attempt so far:** I've used first step decomposition to get an answer of $9.5$ days to the first part of the question, but I have no idea how to find the variance for part (b). I've tried using the Law of Total Variance but got nowhere. I don't know whether you're supposed to use $Var(X) = E(X^2) - (E(X))^2$, where $X$ is the number of days taken to reach freedom. If so, how do you go about finding $E(X^2)$? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can we assume that if the prisoner tries door 1 and returns to his cell, he won't be trying that door again? Would a tree diagram help?

Comment: Thanks for your response. You cant make that assumption. If he tries door 1 and ends up back in his cell, then he'll just pick at random again with the same probabilities (pretty dumb prisoner!). I'm pretty sure my answer to (a) is correct - just not sure about (b).

Comment: `A prisoner is trapped in a cell containing three doors`.  How is he trapped if he has 3 doors?  How much food does he have, for these tunnel tours that last 3 days?  If he goes missing, and comes back after 3 days, will the guard notice, and move him to another cell that has no doors? Then there is the existential/self-referential problem: how can a tunnel lead back to the same door? If that were the case, you would need 4 doors, not 2 (unless they fed into each other, which you exclude by the different travelling time). In essence, your problem poses more questions than answers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To calculate $E[X]$ you presumably did $$E[X] = 0.5 E[X+2]+ 0.3 E[X+3]+0.2 E[0]$$ i.e. $$E[X] = 0.5 E[X] + 0.5 \times 2+ 0.3 E[X] +0.3 \times 3$$ and then solved to find $E[X]$.

Similarly you can do $$E[X^2] = 0.5 E[(X+2)^2]+ 0.3 E[(X+3)^2]+0.2 E[0^2]$$ i.e. $$E[X^2] = 0.5 E[X^2] +0.5 \times 4 E[X] +0.5 \times 4 + 0.3 E[X^2] +0.3 \times 6 E[X]+0.3 \times 9$$ and you already know $E[X]$.  Then use  $Var(X) = E[X^2] - (E[X])^2$

Answer (score 1):

A general approach: Let $X$ the time when de prisoner is free. We will calculate $m_X(t)=E[e^{tX}]$. Let $Y$ the first door choosen.

Note that

$\begin{eqnarray}E[e^{tX}]&=&\sum_{y}E[e^{tX}|Y=y]P(Y=y)\\
&=&E[e^{tX}|Y=1]0.5+E[e^{tX}|Y=2]0.3+E[e^{tX}|Y=3]0.2\end{eqnarray}$

Now, given $Y=1$, $X=2+Z$ where $Z$ is the number of additional days to freedom after the prisoner returned to his cell. But once he returned, the experiment is newly the same. Then $X$ and $Z$ have the same distribution. Thus $E[e^{tX}|Y=1]=E[e^{t(2+Z)}]=e^{2t}E[e^{tZ}]=e^{2t}E[e^{tX}]$.

Analogously $E[e^{tX}|Y=2]=e^{3t}E[e^{tX}]$.

Finally, $E[e^{tX}|Y=3]=1$, cause $X=0$.

Therefore $m_X(t)=E[e^{tX}]=0.5e^{2t}m_X(t)+0.3e^{3t}m_X(t)+0.2$. Thus $m_X(t)=\dfrac{0.2}{1-0.5e^{2t}-0.3e^{3t}}$.

Now it is easy to finish:

$E[X]=m_X^\prime(0)=\left.\dfrac{-0.2(-e^{2t}-0.9e^{3t})}{(1-0.5e^{2t}-0.3e^{3t})^2}\right|_{t=0}=9.5$

$E[X^2]=m_X^{\prime\prime}(0)=\left.0.2\left(\dfrac{2(-e^{2t}-0.9e^{3t})^2}{(-0.5e^{2t}-0.3e^{3t}+1)^3}-\dfrac{-2e^{2t}-2.7e^{2t}}{(-0.5e^{2t}-0.3e^{3t}+1)^2}\right)\right|_{t=0}=204$, so $Var(X)=204-9.5^2=113.75$

Comment: I adjusted two of your last three lines since you should have had $E[X]=9.5$ rather than $0.95$, and that affects the variance calculation